# What is the relation between Shang-Chi and the Mandarin in the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

In Marvel Phase 4 there is going to be the new movie *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*. In *Iron Man 3* it was shown that the Ten Rings is an organization whose leader was the Mandarin.

So what is the relation between Shang-Chi and the Mandarin in the original Marvel comics?

Comment: Also, I’m not sure if it’s official but I read somewhere that the Mandarin in IM3 wasn’t he real one. If this is true, then we have zero info about the Mandarin as well..

Comment: We know a bit about the Mandarin but nothing about Shang-Chi. Unless  you want to focus this solely on the Mandarin rather than Shang-Chi this seems FWP to me.

Comment: As far as wen know, even in the comics, they aren't related. There's no reference to the ten rings or Mandarin on Shang-chi's official history page on Marvel. https://www.marvel.com/characters/shang-chi/in-comics

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/2019/07/24/how-the-mandarin-could-be-the-new-version-of-shang-chis-father):

> While it might seem strange to pit Shang-Chi against a villain most
>   commonly associated with Iron Man, this choice backs up a popular
>   theory that the Mandarin will be depicted as Shang-Chi's father in the
>   MCU
>   movie.

and

> The problems here are two-fold. One, Marvel no longer has the rights
>   to the Fu Manchu character. Not only has this made reprinting the
>   early Master of Kung Fu comics difficult, but it's also prevented them from
>   referencing Shang-Chi's parentage in subsequent comics. Two, Fu Manchu
>   is now widely criticized as a racist caricature and an example of the
>   "Yellow Peril" storytelling trope. Even if Marvel could bring Fu
>   Manchu into the MCU, it's doubtful they'd actually want to use a
>   villain with such a problematic history.

So Shang-Chi and Mandarin are not related at all in the comics, but rather Mandarin will be replacing a character that Marvel cannot (and probably should not) use.

Please note that they are referring to the "real" Mandarin (revealed in the Marvel one-shot [All Hail the King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUU8OBEXhw8)), rather than the "fake" played by Ben Kingsley.

Answer (score 4):

While Raj's answer is correct about the main comics, during the Secret Wars event, one of the alternate Battleworld settings featured a character that was essentially a cross between parts Fu Manchu and the Mandarin, and was Shang-Chi's father. This setting was a basically a big martial arts mashup and replaced the Mandarin's physical ten rings with a "Ten Rings" school of Kung Fu. This school taught various magical/elemental techniques that mimicked the Mandarin ring's powers in the main comics universe.

See:
https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Master_of_Kung_Fu_Vol_2_1
https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/K%27un-Lun_(Battleworld)

Answer (score -3):

Um...they have the same powerset, which is to say the ability to make their bodies superhuman by channeling mystic chi into it. And they are both supremely skilled martial artists. Those are the only things they have in common as far as I know.